# How to enable the tagfeed in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

So I've been messing around with the my companies SharePoint website attempting to fix some things that have been broken since we transitioned to it a month ago. One of the things that my users want, is a control that we see on the internet.

[image: Example]

The issue, is that I can't for the life of me figure out how to put these two controls back into the webpage. From what I can tell, when you create a SharePoint page they are in the 'Newsfeed' page by default and the page itself is called default.aspx. However the only thing that is in our default.aspx is the company newsfeed itself.

I've already tried to revert the page, which didn't do anything. I've also found the Control_TagFeed.html and .js pages, but I'm not really sure where I should be adding those. Any tips / explanations will be appreciated. Ideally you'll know where I can find these two items as a webpart that I can download since I'll know what to do with those.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that each one has a web part associated with it. I haven't been able to find the 'Whats Happening' web part (the top part). The bottom one however is called 'Analytics Hash Tag' web part and I found out how to add it from the following link. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261736(v=office.15).aspx

At the bottom of that page there is the section called Add a component to the Web Part Gallery. That section tells you how to find all the web parts that you can add to your page, and for me the Analytics hash tag web part was one that I could add.